# Deploy JHipster app to Heroku cases JHipster Admin menus "AP"I and "Database" to disappear

Tags: jhipster

I can run my JHipster app locally and I have access to the API and Database menus when logged in as Admin. When I deploy to Heroku these menus are not available in my app. I know the database is configured and I can add entities. I am also not able to access the Swagger API definition page.

I am using tokens for authentication and deploying to Heroku with 'jhipster heroku' command.

Comment: Have you verified that your user really has ROLE_ADMIN authority? Do you see it in authenticate JSON response in browser console?

Answer (score 0):

I realize now after understanding more about how jHipster manages databases, that the issue was liquibase did not run, which means the database was not populated with the initial set of users. The solution would be to configure the prod setting to allow liqubase to run.